# Cannot edit profile

Tags: profile

I have a profile that I cannot edit because I got the following error
"Permission" on "Object" can't be granted, Grant the permission using a permission set with the required license or use a permission set not associated with a specific license, I have a org that has no CPQ installed, is there a way I can solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to edit standard profile or custom profile?